# What is the best way to insert if not exist, otherwise update in entityframework core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here is the model:

```
public class UserModel
{
        public boolean Online{ get; set; }        
        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }

}
```

And here is the DBContext:

```
 public class UserDBContext:DbContext
 {
        public virtual DbSet<UserModel> UserStatus { get; set; }
        public UserDBContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected UserDBContext()
        {
        }
}
```

When there is a user online status needs to record into the database.

If the `id` does not exist in the database then insert it.

If the `id` exists in the database then update it.

Now I do it like this:

```
public async Task SetUserStatus(UserModel UM)
{

    if (UserDBContext.UserStatus.Where(X => X.id == UM.id).Count() != 0)
    {
       UserDBContext.UserStatus.Update(UM);
    }
    else
    {
       UserDBContext.UserStatus.Add(UM);
    }
    UserDBContext.SaveChanges();                      
}
```

In spite it works, I am worried about the performance while there is million data. The database will calculate all the data for the count while I just need one.

How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) instead

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
>   condition.

```
if (UserDBContext.UserStatus.Any(X => X.id == UM.id))
{
   UserDBContext.UserStatus.Update(UM);
}
```